# Yii2 HTML helper input make required

Tags: javascript, yii2

I have form generated with [HTML helper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class='form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-6'>
    <?= HTML::label('Name:','PropertyContactsNew',['class' => 'control-label']); ?>
    <?= HTML::textInput("PropertyContactsNew[{$slug_other_contacts}][name][]", '', ['maxlength' => 50, 'class'=>'form-control']) ?>
  </div>
  <div class='form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-6'>
    <?= HTML::label('Company:','PropertyContactsNew',['class' => 'control-label']); ?>
    <?= HTML::textInput("PropertyContactsNew[{$slug_other_contacts}][company][]", '', ['maxlength' => 100, 'class'=>'form-control']) ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way mark form fields required and prevent form from submitting in case the it is empty, just like the ActiveForm does (I can not use ActiveForm for some reasons) or should I use js library to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you could create a FormModel that extends Model class, so you can handle every validation you need.

Answer (score 3):

Someone might need

```
<?= HTML::label('Name:','PropertyContactsNew',['class' => 'control-label','required'=>true]); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Red required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ6TP.png)

> Only this code is working for me. Div with
>   *class* ***required***

```
<div class="form-group required">
     <?= Html::label('Pressed digit', 'pressed_digit', ['class' => 'control-label']) ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if setting the required class actually make this a required form input. This is more styling related than actual functionality.

Comment: @PascalRaszyk the js validation works correctly with intimating the errors if the wrapper div with the `required` class is there.